# PHP json_decode == NULL on {"action":"online","email":null,"script":null}

Tags: php, json

PHP json_decode is returning null for this JSON string

```
{"action":"online","email":null,"script":null}
```

and the validator shows its valid. Help?

EDIT:
using

```
echo bin2hex($json);
```

I get

```
a bunch of padded zeros on the end  ...c7d00000000 - Unexpected control character found
```

Need to get rid of them somehow..

The Answer:

Seems we found the problem. Try

```
  $json = trim($json), if it don't fix use $json = preg_replace('/\\\\0+$/', '', $json)
```

– Havenard

Comment: can you post the full code?

Comment: Works for me... http://ideone.com/elCCGd

Comment: use `backticks`: ` to include code in your answer

Answer (score 2):

I dont think so, if you wrapped it in `''`  or `""` like this -

While using `""` beware of it in your case, courtesy `msturdy`

```
<?php

$json =  '{"action":"online","email":null,"script":null}';
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
```

Output-

```
array(3) {
  ["action"]=>
  string(6) "online"
  ["email"]=>
  NULL
  ["script"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Codepad - http://codepad.org/AdzSN4R3

**After Comments, from the DOCS**-

> json_decode This function only works with UTF-8 encoded data.

Comment: I am getting error code 3. The json is coming from UTF8 encoded POST from C#.  Think something to do with the encoding.   - Unexpected control character found

Comment: @msturdy thx I updated, although i mentioned it in a general context, but yeah for the particular question it applies too

Comment: @VansS .. can you post more code in your question please?  Helps to have a little more context!

Comment: I'm not sure if UTF-8 would be the problem in this particular case, once it is not using special characters. But you can always try utf8_decode() to filter the input before passing it to json_decode(). Try trim() too to remove any white spaces or newline symbols from the beginning/end of the string.

Comment: @VansS json_decode This function only works with UTF-8 encoded data.

Comment: using echo htmlentities((string)$json); i get  {&quot;action&quot;:&quot;online&quot;,&quot;email&quot;:null,&quot;script&quot;:null}

Comment: @VansS You need to encode the data set with UTF-8 and then apply `json_decode()`

Comment: What `echo bin2hex($json);` says ?

Comment: @swapnesh this particular string has nothing to be encoded, the output of utf8_encode($json) will be the same as the input.

Comment: @Havenard I already answered about the particular case, but i am only appending my answer in general context, as he keeps on appending his question multiple times

Comment: I see 8 zeros padded to the end. Doh.. its because im using AES ZeroPadding to decrypt it.. but in C# they appear as \0  here I couldnt even they where there.  How can I get rid of them from the string?

Comment: Seems we found the problem. Try `$json = trim($json)`, if it don't fix use `$json = preg_replace('/\\\\0+$/', '', $json)`

Comment: @Havenard post the thing as an answer(try to be descriptive for future visitors), glad to up vote it :)

Answer (score 0):

What you have posted is certainly valid JSON:

```
$ echo '{"action":"online","email":null,"script":null}' | python -mjson.tool
{
    "action": "online", 
    "email": null, 
    "script": null
}
```

Most likely, there is something going on with the encoding. Are you submitting via a browser? Perhaps you could utilize its developer tools to gain insight into exactly how the data is being sent? (or sniff the wire...)